# WCF REST issue: where is service.basic.svc.cs

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I just started to use WCF Rest project template to design a REST service, for example Collection REST WCF Collection service.

One thing I noticed that the Service.basic.svc.cs file is no longer under the Service.svc as its partial or dependent class file. I tried to find the definitions for CollectionServiceBase and ICollectionService in Service.svc.cs:

```
public class Service : 
      CollectionServiceBase<SampleClass>, ICollectionService<SampleClass>
...
```

those two classes are actually in my %temp% folder as readonly files. It looks like that they are not for editing. How can I make changes of their attributes such as UriTemplate strings? Not sure if I can bring those files back to the project so that I have control of those files (change definitions or remove some interfaces)? I think there may be reason to this change (compare to the example in some of video shows by endpoint.tv Screencasts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finally I got an answer at ASP.Net forum, [WCF REST Startkit discussion group](http://forums.asp.net/p/1464647/3383982.aspx#3383982) saying that the codes in Service.basic.svc.cs are moved to Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll. This makes it hard to customize some class attributes to customize template url or xml node names. I was suggested to get the source codes to make changes if I need, but I don't think it is good idea.